# Jquery Mobile Dynamic listview with scroll options

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, listview, jquery-mobile, cordova

I'm creating a web app using Jquery Mobile.One of my feature requires me to dynamically load the contents of the listview.

But on refreshing the listview each time for new items, i'm again focused to the top of the listview.

My requirement is to add dynamic contents and view must be focused to the latest content.

Android provides `setSelectionFromTop(index, top);` I want a equivalent API which works along with phonegap to perform that task?

Any other idea is also welcome.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm marking this one up, as I find jQuery Mobile's documentation to be God Awful and have had trouble figuring out this same issue.  I really wish the same people that did jQueryUI''s documentation would do jQueryMobile's

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **`$.mobile.silentScroll` (method)**
>  Scroll to a particular Y position without triggering scroll event listeners. 
> · Arguments: yPos
>   (number, defaults to 0). Pass any number to scroll to that Y location.
>   Examples:

```
//scroll to Y 100px             
$.mobile.silentScroll(100);
```

jQM Docs:

- http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0.1/docs/api/methods.html

Comment: Thanks @Phill Pafford, but when the list contents are dynamic, how to calibrate the "Y-position".Is there any means to do so ?

Comment: First load the dynamic page, find the element you need, get it Y position and then $.mobile.silentScroll(Y);

Comment: Thanks Phil Pafford $('#id').top returns the Y-Coordinate.